# 3-way git merge and manually picking each difference

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

Regarding git: I have two branches b1 and b2 with a common ancestor a. Is it possible to merge b1 and b2 in such a way that i see all the diffs of b1 and b2 up until a, indicated with <<< and >>> inside the code so that I can choose for each diff which one I would like to have?

**Edit:** This question is not primarily about conflict-resolution, but about seeing all the differences between two branches, highlighted inside the code, whether they are conflictual or not. So I can choose which changes I would like to keep. Currently those problematic changes are merged into our development branch without any conflict. During the merge I get two types of files: *modified* and *both modified*. The latter I can review and decide to stage. The former are somehow staged without my consent!

Answer (score 2):

Set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging Check the portion related to `diff3`.

Comment: Makes sense.... let me add the important stuff to the response.

Comment: The OP is not asking about conflicts.

Comment: @matt: thanks! That's right. I'm asking about indicating all the changes between two codes, whether they are conflictual or not.